# Inter process communication between c and PHP using socket

Tags: php, sockets

I created socket using c program and Im trying to connect it by a PHP script. and after connection im reading some values from client side, after reading the value 
and it is displaying on web browser, after displaying the client side(php script) is closing, i want to my php script to hold the same connection after reading. and it is connecting as a new client every time im refreshing. i want php script to hold the same connection.